# Pear broken after PHP downgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, pear

I downgraded PHP from 5.3 to 5.2 by doing something similar to [mrkandy's script](http://mrkandy.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/install-php-5-2-x-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid/)
Everything works fine except pear. `pear list` shows the pear packages I installed before the downgrade and they all work. Pear itself doesn't though. I can no longer install or upgrade any packages and there are no errors displayed.
The .tgz's are downloaded and I can see them in `/build/buildd/php5-5.2.10.dfsg.1/pear-build-download/` but that's as far as it goes, nothing is installed.
I can't seem to find any log of the process and I don't know how to run `pear install` in verbose mode (if there is such a thing).
Does anybody have any hints for me, some threads to pull?

I am using Linux Mint 9 (a lot like ubuntu 10.04)

```
$ pear config-show
Configuration (channel pear.php.net):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    <not set>
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /usr/bin
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /usr/share/php/doc
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /usr/lib/php5/20060613+lfs
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /usr/share/php
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /tmp/pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /usr/share/php/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /usr/share/php/data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /build/buildd/php5-5.2.10.dfsg.1/pear-build-download
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /usr/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          <not set>
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /tmp/pear/temp
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /usr/share/php/test
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /usr/share/php/htdocs
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            22
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /etc/pear/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /home/clive/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /etc/pear/pear.conf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue with Ubuntu 10.04. All I had to do was to upgrade PEAR with -Z option.

> sudo pear upgrade -Z PEAR

worked like a charm for me.

And if you want to install PHPUnit afterwards use the same -Z option.

> sudo pear install -Z phpunit/PHPUnit

Comment: I was expecting to be able to install pear packages in the normal way after this fix but this is not the case. However the -Z option seems to work `sudo pear install -Z PACKAGE` so my problem is solved. Thanks hijas